# Duplicate existing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

As **Turbolinks** are deprecated on Android, I'm trying to implement a small fraction of it's functionality myself.

What I'm trying to do is to use NavController and Fragments within my application. The Fragment pretty much only contains a webview.

Now, when someone taps on something in that webview, instead of loading a new page inside that webview, I'd like to programatically create a new (instance of a) Fragment and have the NavController to navigate to the new "page". The advantage would be to get a transition plus I can use the system back button to navigate to previous pages.

At this point I'm not even sure this is possible to do.

the `navigate()` method takes a fragment ID. If I pass the same ID as the current top-most fragment, nothing happens. So, my idea was to somehow create a duplicate of the current fragment and pass something like `navigate(ID_x)`.

Please note that I'm new to Android and I might be missing something fundamental.

Edit: as request in comments, here as an example

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("number", 5);

navController.navigate(R.id.open_category, args);
```

"open_category" is an `<action>` which should display a new instance of the same fragment. That actually happens (at least the `onCreateView()` is called) but NavController won't put the new fragment on the top of the stack and I can't got back to the "old" fragment instance.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/open_category"
    app:destination="@id/navigation_blank"
    />
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to implement your own navigation the "old fashioned" way with the fragment manager. You can still achieve what you want, I have no doubt, but you'll need to not use the NavController. This should be useful (hopefully): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragment_transitions.htm

Comment: NavController certainly allows multiple instances of the same type of fragment on the top of the stack. Show your code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake please take a look on the code above. Can I pass an argument to the NavController which would allow me to navigate between the two instances?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have figured this out. The part I left out was that I'm also using BottomNavigationView and that made some part a bit tricky. I did not know it's relevant. I may create a git repo for the case other people are struggling with the same thing. Anyway - thanks for the hint. The confidence this can be done was precisely what I needed.